# How to quickly checksum a MySQL InnoDB table with millions of records

Tags: mysql, innodb, checksum, delta

I have InnoDB based tables that I can checksum with:

```
checksum table _table_name_
```

That is slow in case millions of records reside in the table. I wonder if there is any way to recognize, whether a table was altered or not?

I needed something that is fast and cheap to request, and changes every time a change is made to any of the records of a table. I do not find anything for InnoDB tables. Is there something?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timestamp (say `LastUpdateTS`) on the table, created with default settings, and an index on it, then this should be rather fast. It will catch only Inserts and Updates but not Deletes though:

```
SELECT MAX(LastUpdateTS)
FROM TableX
```

From **[`MySQL Docs, Timestamp Properties`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html)**:

> In a `CREATE TABLE` statement, the first `TIMESTAMP` column can be declared in any of the following ways:
>
> With both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.

---

If you want to catch any change in the table (Deletes included), a trigger may be the best solution. Every time an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement acts on the table, the trigger can update an auxilary table.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. In case of DB's under heavy load I dont know how much impact 3 additional triggers would have. Therefore I decided to add a timestamp column and include the number of rows of a table to realize delete actions as well. This means some migrations but seems to be the best tradeof.

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of MySQL stores a timestamp for each update to the table:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Comment: That seem to be slow too and returns NULL for a lot of tables where I did not expect NULL.